# Add Environment Variable to PATH

Tags: bash, path, environment-variables

I am new to the Apple "eco system" and I am trying to setup my **environment variables** for local development.

Here is what I have in my `~/.bash_profile` (simplified for brevity):

```
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$DEV_CLI:$PATH"
export DEV_CLI="/path/to/cli/$BRANCH_NAME/bin"
export BRANCH_NAME=dev
```

What I want here is to have my dev cli accessible from **any** point in the terminal. The crucial thing here is I want to **change** the `BRANCH_NAME` on different occasions.

Currently my solution works only if I do `source ~/.bash_profile` in every terminal tab/window I use.

So let's say that I open new terminal and do:

1. `echo $DEV_CLI` - it will be printed,
2. `echo $PATH` - the path for the cli will be missing there
3. `source ~/.bash_profile`
4. `echo $PATH` - all variables set in the path will be shown (cli path including)

I am running on Mac **High Seirra**.

Any help explanation will be deeply appreciated!

Comment: What is "cli. path"? You do not want an empty PATH variable at any point in your terminal. session.

Comment: I fail to see your point, which variable you think is empty? Note that the values here  are fiction ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your variables are out of order.**    You cannot set a variable based on  other variables defined *after* it.

Set the commands in your `~/.bash_profile` to the following:

```
export BRANCH_NAME=dev
export DEV_CLI="/path/to/cli/$BRANCH_NAME/bin"
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$DEV_CLI:$PATH"
```

Why this is happening...

1. When you open a new shell, it reads `~/.bash_profile`
2. It sets a `PATH` environment variable with other environment variables that aren't defined yet (`DEV_CLI` and `BRANCH_NAME`)
3. The environment variables are then defined
4. You re-source `~/.bash_profile` and sets the `PATH` again, this time with defined variables

It's important to note that this has nothing to do with the Apple "eco system," per se.  This is a Bash issue, and more generally a *shell* issue; you would literally have this problem whether you were on Apple, BSD, Linux, Unix and even Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification - in the example I mistakenly switched the positions of `BRANCH_NAME` and `DEV_CLI` but still the `PATH` variable was on top of them anyway.